# react-hook-form useFieldArray with nested array

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I need to update useFieldArray when the number of elements of the child array defaultValues changes.

or I need to make append to the nested useFieldArray from the top-level (parent) component where the child array index is not known.

Tried to recreate and experiment with setValue. But the result is not very good: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-uj5im?file=/src/index.js

Comment: can you please be more clear on what's required here? Maybe specify some expected value vs original value.

Comment: There is two ways of solving the problem. I already have working logic without react-hook-form, so I've got there working methods of adding and deleting nested elements. I can use them and they would change the defaultValues of the form - the only problem is: the form doesn't trigger this change. So the user doesn't see the changed data until refresh the page. U can reproduce this case, by clicking the "Change defaultValues" button in the sandbox, and check the console output.

Comment: But I want to implement the logic with react-hook-forms because  in the future I'll got more logic with it. So it's better to add or remove elements of array with reat-hook-form append, remove. I can do it.
The problem here is in the deep nested array, I can not control it outside the component in which i render this array with the array index.
I have to control it from the parrent component, I've tryed to do it with getValues and setValue, but it looks wierd, and there must be a way to make it with append(), but I'm stuck and it doesnt work...